# How do you earn the Strunk & White badge?

Tags: support, badges, editing

It says on the Badges page "Edited 80 posts".

When you click the link below it says I've 102 edits.

Are only certain types of edits eligible for the badge or is this an error?

https://movies.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all

Comment: Interesting.  Typically it takes a couple hours for the site to run its processes for badges, but I assume you hit 80 edits a while ago.  I'll ping someone who knows more than I do and get back to you on this one.

Comment: I hit 80 a whole ago but I waited until I got to 100 just in case it was a typo and should've been 100 edits for the Badge but still no good! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right - not all edits count towards the badge. In particular, edits on your own posts and edits that only change the tags are excluded.

By our count, you currently have 59 edits that are contributing to the badge, so you just have 21 to go.